# how to find interval of convergence of Taylor series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I have problem with Taylor series of the function $$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x+4}$$ around x=2. I calculated the derivatives and then subtitute into formula, but I don't know what to do next. Could someone explain it to me step-by-step?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{x+4}=\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{ 1- \frac{2-x}{6} }$

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see that:
$\displaystyle\frac{1}{x+4}=\frac{1}{x+4+2-2}=\frac{1}{(x-2)+6}=\frac{1}{6[\frac{x-2}{6}+1]}=\frac{1}{6[1-\frac{2-x}{6}]}=\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{2-x}{6}}$

Adding the fact that:

$S_n=1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n$

$x S_n = x+x^2+\ldots+x^{n+1}$

$S_n-xS_n=(1-x)S_n=1-x^{n+1}$

Where we finally get: $S_n=1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n=\displaystyle\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

Thus $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n+\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

Use the Taylor's subtitution property with $x=\frac{2-x}{6}$, and multiply the whole polynomial by $\frac{1}{6}$.

Then, $\displaystyle T_n\bigg(\frac{1}{x+4},0\bigg)(x)=\frac{1}{6}T_n\bigg(\frac{1}{1-\frac{2-x}{6}},0\bigg)\displaystyle=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=0}^n\bigg(\frac{2-x}{6}\bigg)^k+R_n\bigg(\frac{1}{x+4},0\bigg)(x)$

Where $\displaystyle R_n\bigg(\frac{1}{x+4},0\bigg)(x)=\bigg(\frac{2-x}{6}\bigg)^{n+1}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{2-x}{6}}$

Hope it helps.